# Get index of spline by attribute

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a groups of splines each one with a unique id which doesn't match its on index and represents how they are sorted in the z axis. I need to get each spline's index by its id.

So for instance, my lowest spline with id "0" has index "2", the next one has id "1" and index "5", the next one id "2" with index "8" and so on.

How can I get each spline index by just watching its id using geometry nodes?

Comment: For *N* splines, does the id is also in the range *0* to *N-1* ? Or could the id be negative or greater or equal to *N* ?

Comment: both lists are the same lenght and have same range, just diferent  order.

Comment: Could you illustrate what you are doing that requires to list splines by increasing ID instead of index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

#### First proposal

Following is a proposal where:

- a first line with as many points as there are splines is created, and the spline ID is transferred to the line point sharing the same *Index*,
- a second line is created with the same number of points, but a *Points of Curve* node is used to sort the first set of points using *ID* as weight. This time, the first set of points *Index* is stored.

To recover a spline *Index* from its *ID*, you can use a *Sample Index* node with the input socket *Geometry* connected to the second line, the input socket *Value* connected to a *Named Attribute* node with *Name* set to "index", the input socket *Index* connected to the spline ID value. The output socket *Value* is returning the spline index.

[image: GN Graph]

**Resources:** [image]

---

#### Simplified graph

Eventually, the first line is not required !

[image: Simplified GN graph]

Comment: (NB: this comment will be deleted when the answer is stabilized) I am running out of time to write a better and more detailed explanation. If this first draft fulfil your need, I will rewrite this answer. If not, criticize it and I will try to improve it.

Comment: I'm acepting the answer as valid as it solves the question, still this solution won't be useful for more generic purposes, imagine the splines aren't sorted by height and their ids are completely random, how do I get their index by looking at its attribute?